# Adding video into the picture with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, video-editor, ffmpeg, windows

How to Adding video into the picture with ffmpeg?

example:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`overlay` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay):

[image]

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i overlay.mp4 -filter_complex \
"overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h:shortest=1" output.mp4
```

Comment: @RannielBirao You can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it works for you.